# In Pidgin, perl.dll is not loadable error

Tags: windows-7, windows, perl, dll, pidgin

I can find this error in Pidgin's (version Pidgin 2.12.0, libpurple 2.12.0) debug window:

```
(17:57:27) plugins: C:\Program Files (x86)\Pidgin\plugins\perl.dll is not loadable: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Pidgin\plugins\perl.dll': The specified module could not be found.
```

Now the module is there:

[image]

So I'm assuming that either there's an architecture mismatch or the module is completely corrupted.

How can I fix this? Is `perl.dll` generic perl module?

Comment: Actually I downloaded the last available version of pidgin to fix this issue and it persisted. I don't know where the debug.log file is.

Comment: If you take look on the screenshot and the text in question, it says there that the file is in the pidgin directory, just cannot be loaded for some reason.

Comment: @Ramhound I can't tell, but as written in the question, I have a suspicion that it's 64bit and therefore not compatible with my 32bit pidgin. Where is the debug.log file?

Comment: I can't find any such file. And I don't have the 32 bit version. If I did, I would try it of course. But I only have what's pidgin distributed with, no other dlls

Comment: I completely understand the generic error.  I have used Pidgin in the past, used it for over 4 years, has been awhile.  My research into the issue indicates this is a problem with a registry key, and the debug.log file, would confirm if that’s the case.  I am getting the impression you don’t want my help.  So I am removing my comments.  When you provide the required information from the log file I will answer your question.  Which plugin did you add requires Perl?

Comment: The issue your running into is that Windows is unable to find the module, Windows has a specific locations which are checked, when a required file isn’t in the same folder as the executable (which is the case here).